# How can i retrieve Azure app service certificate details using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to retrieve app service certificate details , but it only retrieves for the entire ResourceGroup using powershell as follows:

```
az webapp config ssl list --resource-group  "TestResourceGroup" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

There are a number of app services in this resource group. I want the certificate details for a certain app service not all .

How can i get the details for a particular app service ?

Comment: [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) returns an object graph (nested `[pscustomobject]` instances or arrays thereof). Use dot notation to drill down into that graph, e.g. `$result = az ... | ConvertFrom-Json; $result.myAppService.Certificate` (adapt this to the actual structure of the data being returned).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `az webapp config ssl show --resource-group <RG_val> --certificate-name <naked_FQDN>` (not sure what you need to return). Or alternatively use a JMESPath on the `az webapp config list` to control what you are returning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mklement0, I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
$r=az webapp config ssl list --resource-group XX
$r.WebAppName.Certificate
$r | ConvertFrom-Json
```

XX- Name of the resource group

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear it, but note that `$r` - before passing it to `ConvertFrom-Json` - is either a _string_ or an array thereof (one element for each output line). Thus, `$r.WebAppName.Certificate` yields `$null` - as opposed to something like `($r | ConvertFrom-Json).WebAppName.Certificate`